# How do I use alert() for a long debug message?

Tags: javascript, alert

I'm trying to `alert()` the properties of the javascript object. Since the text in alert isn't scrollable, I can see only part of it. How do I fix this? I'm using FF 3.5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and use [`console.log(myObj);`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/javascript-what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it)

You can inspect the object properly in this way!

Comment: The only tricky bit to keep in mind about using console.log is it will cause an error when you run the script with the firebug pane closed.

Comment: @Erik: `if (console.log) console.log(myObj);`

Comment: or, `if (!console) console = { log: function() {} };`

Comment: @MatthewCrumley: That will throw an error if `console` doesn't exist. Use `window.console` instead: `if (!window.console) window.console = { log: function() {} };`

Answer (score 2):

You can split the text into many pieces and alert many different times.
Or, you can make a textArea on the page and set the innerHTML of the textarea to your output message [what I do] Note that if you want to do that, you have to replace \n with <br />

In chrome, sometimes the "okay" button of the alert doesn't even show >_>

Comment: Going to have to mention this method is severely outdated unless you desire to see the intermediate state of your application. Opt for console.log as it is less intrusive. Also consider executing "debugger;" which will cause a breakpoint if you have chrome/firebug's console open.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cross-browser logging library such as my own [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/). Among many other things, it has a searchable, filterable logging console and allows you to dump objects to the console using logging calls:

```
var obj = {
    name: "Octopus",
    tentacles: 8
};

log.debug(obj);

/*
   Displays:

   19:53:17 INFO  - {
     name: Octopus,
     tentacles: 8
   }
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Blackbird](http://www.gscottolson.com/blackbirdjs/). It's an onscreen javascript logger/debugger. In you code you would place log.debug(object) and it will be output to the browser in a div overlay. I don't know if it works if you just pass it an object, but apparently you already have the object.dumpvars() already worked out.