# What is console.log and how do I use it?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539253/what-is-console-log)

I see this line in a lot of jQuery scripts out there. I assume it's used for debug.

Where can I see this log?