# Why do I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting the understand the use of the `document` object type and to challenge myself I am trying to hide all the `div` tags. When I execute the function, I am returned the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined` however am unsure what it means exactly. What is undefined?

The output of the code can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/Bdbtq/

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-us" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="&copy; 2012" />
    <meta name="robot" content="noindex, nofollow" />

    <title>js features</title>

    <base href="" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="" />

    <style type="text/css" media="all">

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="content">
            <p>This is sample content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">&copy; 2012</div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function hideMe() {
        //hide all div elements
        var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

        for(var i = 0; i < div.length; i = i + 1) {
            div.style.display="none";
        }
    }

    </script>
    <p onClick="hideMe();">Click to hide</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `div.style` seems to be undefined.

Comment: @Hunter McMillen - What do you mean `div.style` is undefined?

Comment: `div` in your for loop is an array of div elements. It does not have a style member, therefore div.style resolves to `undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array. So you need:

```
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i = i + 1) {
        divs[i].style.display="none";
    }
```

Comment: The thing I don't get is if I do `document.write(div[i]);` I get the output as `[object HTMLDivElement]`. Why is that?

Comment: Because `div[i]` is a single div. Your `div` variable contains all of the divs in your webpage. If you index into this array, you can get at individual divs. so `div[0]` is the first div, `div[1]` is the second, and so on and so forth.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey If you `document.write(div[1])` you are not writing the contents of the div, but a string representation of the object itself. If you want what's inside it, use `document.write(div[1].innerHTML);`.  When you request a string representation of many objects in JS (like if you try to write them out or alert() them, they internally call a `toString()` method which puts them into some readable format. It happens that DOM nodes will output in the format `[object HTMLSomeElement]` Other things might just say `[object object]`

Comment: Or better yet, `document.body.appendChild(div[i])`

Answer (score 3):

Div is an array of elements, not a single element. Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < div.length; i = i + 1) {
    div[i].style.display="none";
}
```

I think it would be easier to avoid these mistakes if you call your variable `divs`, or something similar that indicates that it isn't an element.

Comment: Yeah. I kept wrecking my brain as to what I was I doing wrong.

Comment: I am although confused to as asked by me to Michael why I get `[object HTMLDivElement]` if I call the array by its position i.e. [1]

Comment: Because `div[i]` is a HTMLDivElement object. What sort of value were you expecting to get?

Comment: I was expecting the `div` element and its values e.g. content, etc

Comment: You have to add `.innerHTML` to actually get the element's content. But if this is just for debugging purposes, I find it a lot easier to use [console.log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/javascript-what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it) and view the result in the browser's web inspector. If you write `console.log(div);` it will display an array of div elements. If you write `console.log(div[i]);` it will show exactly what you were expecting (the element & its attributes/content).

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `div` is at this point a node list, not a single variable, as [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) returns a node list.  You need to access it via its array index from your loop as in `div[i]`

```
for(var i = 0; i < div.length; i = i + 1) {
    // div[i] holds the current loop iteration
    div[i].style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: @Michael- Thanks. Could I have been so silly to have missed that? n00b mistake.

Comment: Awarded Matt the answer as you included your comments in the same post. I did however up vote your comments.