# json_encode returning no values

Tags: php, json

I am developing a webservice using php and MSSQL.I could connect with db and retriev values.But when I use json,It will return no values.

The ajax code used for web service is

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://209.249.81.138/dev/logintalk.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "username=" + $("#username").val()+"&password=" + $("#password").val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure...");
        }
       });
}
```

and the php code used is

```
<?php

    $server = "server";
    $username = "username";

    $password = "secret";
    $database = "db";

    $con = mssql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $Server");

    $users = $_POST['username'];
    $passwd = $_POST['password'];

    $selected = mssql_select_db($database, $con) or die("Couldn't open database $database");

    mssql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8'); 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM zNewUsers WHERE memberid = '$users' AND userid = '$passwd'";
    $result = mssql_query($query) or die ("Unable to verify user because ");
    $row = mssql_fetch_array($result);
    $count = mssql_num_rows($result);

    if($count == 0){
        $data=array(0=>"Incorrect values...");
        $value[]=$data[0];
        echo json_encode($value);
    }
    else{
    $val[]=$row['SessionID'];
    echo json_encode($val);
    }  
    mssql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: When you open the PHP file in your browser, do you see the JSON output? Also, instead of using `alert()` for javascript debugging, use [console.log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/javascript-what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it).

Comment: Also: use the developer tools of your browser to inspect what data is returned. Maybe the script returns nothing because of a syntax error.

Comment: @Balu: You need to change your DB's root password **right now**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few tips beyond question:

1. ```
   success: function(data){
       console.log(data);
       //This is better for debugging if you use firebug, if you don't do it.
   },
   ```
2. ```
   if($count == 0){
       echo json_encode(array(0=>"Incorrect values..."));
       //Why create new variables? Pass what you want directly to json_encode()
   }
   else{
       echo json_encode($row['SessionID']);
   }
   ```

Back to question:

var_dump() data you want to encode before encoding and make sure it's OK, then check what you get in browser by `console.log(data)` and share this information with us so we could help better.