# Return a new order of the elements after a drag and drop event in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I have place my sample at the below location : http://jsbin.com/axegem/1

Here is the scenario. When I drag the divs and drop them on to another place, I need to retrieve the new order of the divs. For example, lets say (with respect to my sample), I dragged and dropped **DIV 3** after **DIV 6**. Now I am trying to get the new order of the divs. For testing, I am alerting their html text in the following code:

```
$(".draggable").each(function(){
  alert($(this).html());
});
```

I am expecting the alert order to be: **DIV 1, DIV 2, DIV 4, DIV 5, DIV 6, DIV 3, DIV 7, DIV 8, DIV 9**. But what I get in the sample is **DIV 1, DIV 2, DIV 3, DIV 4, DIV 5, DIV 6, DIV 7, DIV 8, DIV 9**.

How can I get the new order of the divs after dropping them in a new location?

Comment: You are only moving the position of the div, not changing the order. I recommend using `.sortable()` since you are already using jQuery. http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Comment: Side note: please use `console.log()` rather than `alert()`.  Seeing 30 alerts makes me want to punch someone in the face. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it

Comment: I am just using this for testing. I'll use your suggestion. Thanks for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have change a little your code to fit your needs.

I have change to using [**Sortable**](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default) functionality, that's because you have used the **draggable** the only drug not sort elements.

When you use the Sortable it will be easily to get the sorted elements

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#divOuter2').css("margin","-540px 0 0 400px");
    $('#divOuter3').css("margin","-540px 0 0 800px");

    $(".droppable").sortable({
      update: function( event, ui ) {
        Dropped();
      }
    });



  });



    function Dropped(event, ui){
      $(".draggable").each(function(){
        //var p = $(this).position();
        alert($(this).html());
      });
      refresh();
    }
```

I have set the DOM element with class `.droppable` as sortable.

Then on [Update](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) Event i am calling your function `Dropped`

[See Example](http://jsbin.com/axegem/10/edit)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs guys. I got to change my whole logic from draggable/droppable to use sortable. I got the solution much quicker here than the msdn blog.

Comment: I am bit confused here while I am working in this issue. My **Dropped()** function is calling twice here: http://jsbin.com/axegem/15/

Comment: I have looked at your code and i don't see where it is calling twice. Am i missing something?

Comment: I tried in both IE and firefox. When I drag and drop a DIV, I can see "Dropped" alert twice.

Comment: I noticed a weird behavior. When you drop **Div 3** under **Div 6**, you see the "Dropped" alert twice. If you drop **Div 5** under **Div 6**, you see it only once. Why is that so?

Comment: i have some elements in each div, and one of them is a span element that contain the "move" image, so this way i want drag to function only within span, and not anywhere on the div body. how can i work this out ? thank you

Comment: @armen - look at this link http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle you can use handle to achieve that

Answer (score 3):

The problem about draggable is that all it does is move items around in a free space and doesn't concern itself with ordering.  Droppable can help, but that's more concerned with figuring out if an object is inside of a container.

Instead of using draggable and droppable, try **sortable**.  It makes things like setting sort order of items incredibly simple. That and you no longer have to worry about it fitting in the proper order either.

Check out this: http://jsbin.com/axegem/6/