# Store Date in localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, local-storage

Using jquery mobile 1.3 I was able to collect and display values from some input fields using localSotorage with this function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function datosCliente (info) {
        localStorage.setItem(info.name,info.value);
    }
</script>
```

And here is a sample of one input field calling the function:

```
<label for="basic">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="basic" data-mini="true" onkeyup="datosCliente(nombre)"/>
```

I was hoping to do the same on an input type date:

```
<label for="fecha">Fecha</label>
        <input name="fecha" id="fecha" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"calbox", "useNewStyle":true}' onkeyup="datosCliente(fecha)" />
```

And the display the value using:

```
<p><span>Fecha: </span><script>document.write(localStorage.getItem("fecha"));</script></p>
```

But is it turns out All I get is null when I want to display the value of this field. Is it because I am using the jQueryMobile - DateBox plugin to pick the date ? Or I have to try a different approach to collect the value from this type of input ?

Comment: How are you saving the date in localStorage? Note than localStorage can only store strings. So if you are giving it an object of type `Date()`, it will store it as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a good idea to use `onchange` rather than `onkeyup`, especially since the browser UI won't trigger keypresses.

Comment: The OP said that he had more inputs working normally. That means that his browser UI is triggering keypresses!

Comment: The problem only seems to be happening with `type="date"`

Comment: Correct, using the mobile date-picker will not trigger the keyup. Good point and it would be better if you mention that it is happening because it's of type `date` in your answer.

Comment: I changed from onkeyup to onchange and it works !! Simple and clever answer !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an answer per-say, but you can try changing nombre and fecha to [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html). And might I add, instead of using document.write, you could use [console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it), that way you can tell if it is an object as opposed to a string, etc. This would probably have gone in the comments section but I don't seem to have the privileges to do that just yet. Good luck.