# Second jquery ajax call doesn't work?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I don't see what i am doing wrong. The second ajax call doesn't work, like the first

```
     $(".payment").click(function(){
     visitorID = $(this).attr('id');
     alert("Modal says "+visitorID);
     $.ajax({ url: 'update.php',
         data: {action: visitorID},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                      alert(output);
                      window.location.reload(); //reload so we see the updated values

                  },
        });     
});//#end click
$(".generateInvoice").click(function(){
     barcode = $(this).attr('barcode');
    alert("Modal says "+barcode);
     //console.log('hello');
     $.ajax({ url: 'generateInvoice.php',
         data: {action: barcode},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                      alert('hi '+output);
                     //console.log('hie');
                      //window.location.reload(); //reload so we see the updated values

                  },
        });     
});//#end click
```

With payment i see both alert boxes, but with generateInvoice i only see the first alert box. For testing purpose i have made generateInvoice.php just reading

```
echo ' there does it work';
die();
```

But with .generateInvoice the alert in the $.ajax doesn't show

Any info?

Comment: Add a [error handler](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) and see what the problem is.

Comment: Do **not** use `alert()`, use [`console.log()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: Have you watched the request with fiddler/your browser dev tools to see what the response from that request contains? If an error is being returned the `success` wont be executed

Comment: This may be the problem: window.location.reload();

Comment: @ToddMurray, the reload has nothing to do with it. The OP was showing two methods that are unrelated other than the basic code.

Comment: @Dom - cant see how using an alert would make a difference... good practice to not use alert-based debugging as the console is richer  but it wont make any difference to the problem.

Comment: @Jamiec I agree. Sorry, should've written "Side Note:" prior. My mistake!

Comment: The issue may be with your php file. Try replacing "generateInvoice.php" with "update.php".

Comment: hello guys, already tried console.log and i am watching the chrome > developer tools >network tab. generateInvoice.php doesn't seemed to be called at all.
btw: i am using both(alert +console.log) for error checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tx for thinking along, but i found my stupid mistake.

It turn out in the HTML the button tag didn't have the type declared, so i added

```
type="button"
```

and now the ajax part is being triggered/called :)

as the first alert was showing it didn't cross my mind

regards