# Jquery Json extract node?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

How can I use Jquery to only extract 'customers_firstname' from the json format?

```
<?php echo json_encode($users) ?>
```

Output

```
[{"Customer":{"id":"13","customers_gender":"M","resumetest":"a15ff2aa27d616636b5bc30fac4dba38733f4e5f","created":"2013-01-29 13:49:06","modified":"2013-03-14 11:50:18","customers_firstname":"Gerald","customers_lastname":"Russ"}},{"Customer":{"id":"14","customers_gender":"F","resumetest":null,"created":"2013-01-29 15:41:23","modified":"2013-02-14 15:08:42","customers_firstname":"Jim","customers_lastname":"Carrie"}}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4Pw3j/3/)

HTML

```
<ul id="nameList">
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var customers = [{"Customer":{"id":"13","customers_gender":"M","resumetest":"a15ff2aa27d616636b5bc30fac4dba38733f4e5f","created":"2013-01-29 13:49:06","modified":"2013-03-14 11:50:18","customers_firstname":"Gerald","customers_lastname":"Russ"}},{"Customer":{"id":"14","customers_gender":"F","resumetest":null,"created":"2013-01-29 15:41:23","modified":"2013-02-14 15:08:42","customers_firstname":"Jim","customers_lastname":"Carrie"}}];

$.each(customers, function (index, item) {

        $("#nameList").append("<li>" + item.Customer.customers_firstname + "</li>");
    });
```

Comment: thanks mate! can i ask? what does console.log() does? how can i append the result in a table <td></td> tag that loop and display on the results.

Comment: For console.log() check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it . Updated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code in your AJAX success block

```
$.each(json_data, function (index, customer){//here json_data is success response from the Server
if (customer){
console.log(customer["customers_firstname"];
}
})
```

Comment: how can do you reference? can you advice?

Comment: means do you want to store customer name in some variable?