# How to know if user closes the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to know if user closes the page, not clicking back button or write another website in url bar to leave. I have tried this,

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {

logout();

});
```

It works, but it fires also when user clicks back button or write another url and go.
My question is, is it possible to know if user closes the page ?

Comment: Why are you trying to exclude the other forms of navigation? Wouldn't you still need to logout in those cases?

Comment: Look at this que.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769514/window-onclose-function

This may suggest you something.

Comment: Do you really mean "know if the user leaves the website?"  because you said pressing back was OK.

Comment: I mean "How to know if user closes the page"

Comment: I think you mean "...closes the browser" or "...closes the current browser tab", because navigating to another website _does_ close the current page - for all intents and purposes except yours, I guess...

Answer (score 2):

There's an alternative but it's **expensive** and also really depends on the user case. It works wonders for me at a simple chat we did. You can have the javascript to constantly (every few seconds) call a page with the user id, `example.com/misc/alive/456457`, where 456457 is the id of the user. You introduce then that call in a database table as a new row. If the user doesn't call back in **more** than X seconds, you assume he's gone.

Of course, you don't get an action just when the user 'is gone', you just get a database that then you've got to analyse to know when the user 'probably' left. For the chat example, it was as easy as calling it every 2 seconds and then checking if there was any user online in the last 5 seconds and delete duplicate ids (to give it some threshold).

Comment: But that method still doesn't do what the OP is asking, i.e., it doesn't distinguish between the browser closing versus navigating to some other site.

Comment: Thanks for the information but it really doesnt what I need. It also tracks if users click back button or type another website and go.