# How to get data from JS popup window when window is closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, windows

I'm trying to capture when a form field from a popup window exists when the window is closed.  I currently do not have control over the child window, but it is on the same domain as the parent window.

I've looked into using the timer functionality:

```
var child = window.open(...);
var timer = setInterval(checkChild, 500);

function checkChild() {
    if (child.closed) {
        <DO SOMETHING HERE>
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
```

but that won't work for me because I don't think that'll give me access to the child's data.

My popup window has a few form fields for uploading a user's profile image.  My question is how would I access whether the user SUBMITTED the form or just simply closed the window?  There is javascript in the popup window for the submit button that will handle actually uploading the image, but I would need to somehow capture when they click the "upload" button and be able to see that the user actually had an image to upload submitted.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I went ahead and just looked into the closed window event.  I couldn't actually get any data from there, but I was able to read further from the DB on the server-side code to get the data I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [child.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event to get information from the child window before it closes.

As suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/15769556/1600851

Comment: Could I access form elements on the popup window from this method?  So like....

`child.getElementById('SomeTextField')` to return the content of 'SomeTextField'?

Comment: Also wouldn't doing this produce a cross-origin error?

POC:  Open a popup in chrome, open console...
`child.onDocumentUnload(function (event) {alert("Window closing");});`
Result:
`SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "..." from accessing a cross-origin frame.`