# How to refresh parent window after user closes popup window?

Tags: javascript

There are many exactly similar questions here on SO, but none give the correct answer, hence forcing me to ask this as a new question. Please consider this before marking my question as a duplicate.

I tried the answers posted in the other questions and none of them work correctly for me. Here is the code I have:

In the parent window:

```
  <a href="createfolder.htm" onClick="return popup(this, 'createfolder', 600, 200);">Create new folder</a>
```

In the Javascript file:

```
function popupClosed() {
  //alert('About to refresh');
  window.location.href = window.location.href;
 //window.opener.location.reload();
}

function popup(mylink, windowname, w, h)
{
  //if (! window.focus) return true;
  var href;
  if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
    href = mylink;
  else
    href = mylink.href;

  var left = (window.innerWidth/2)-(w/2);
  var top = (window.innerHeight/2)-(h/2);

  var win = window.open(href, windowname, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);

  win.onunload = function() {
    popupClosed();
  }

  return false;
}
```

The problem I am having is that it is refreshing the parent window as soon as the link is clicked - which is not desired. It does also refresh the parent window after the popup is closed. However I want to avoid the refresh that occurs when the link is clicked.

Comment: Why `onClick="return popup` and not `onClick="popup`?

Comment: You can post a message to the parent window? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if they changed it, but in the past, the window had no events to call on, so you had to start a interval and check the `closed` state.

**CODE**

```
var win = window.open('http://www.google.com','google','width=800,height=600,status=0,toolbar=0');   
var timer = setInterval(function() {   
    if(win.closed) {  
        clearInterval(timer);  
        alert('closed');  
    }  
}, 1000);
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15769630/2424541

Instead of alerting something, you can refresh the page.

```
window.location.reload();
```

Also if you want to prevent the `href` part of the anchor directing you to the page, you have to prevent the default behaviour.
You can do this with the following:

```
<a href="createfolder.htm" id="popopener" onClick="return popup(this, 'createfolder', 600, 200);">Create new folder</a>

<script>
    document.getElementById('popopener').onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
```

At this part, you can remove the "onClick" part and put it under the `e.preventDefault();` part. This is much cleaner than using `onClick`.

Answer (score 0):

you should disable the default click event behavior of a link by `event.preventDefault();`

**Edit:**

```
<a href="createfolder.htm" onClick="return popup(event, this, 'createfolder', 600, 200);">Create new folder</a>


function popup(event, mylink, windowname, w, h)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  if (! window.focus) return true;
  var href;
  if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
    href = mylink;
  else
    href = mylink.href;

  var left = (window.innerWidth/2)-(w/2);
  var top = (window.innerHeight/2)-(h/2);

  var win = window.open(href, windowname, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);

  win.onunload = function() {
      window.parent.popupClosed();
  };

  return false;
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me. It still re-loads the main window. Using Google Chrome.

Comment: try to pass the event to the popup method then.

Comment: I made the changes as suggested and it still does not work.