# js how to call link with a callback

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, callback

I'm trying to call a URL (like **a** tag) from java script code, I know that there is :

`window.open(url)`

and

```
location.href=url
```

but on top of that, I want to  set a callback function to be called when the called url is closed.
for example I want to create a button, when it clicked it call stackoverflow web site, and then when I close stackoverflow, I want an alert to be launched

**Edit**

I tried the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769514/window-onclose-function) solutions but it is not exactly what I wanted .
here is an example of what I want :

```
window.open( "http://stackoverflow.com");
//I know this event doesn't exist 
window.onclose=function(){
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}
}
```

Comment: it's impossible

Comment: I don't know that what I'm asking

Comment: please clarify your question.