# The delta in mousewheel does not have result

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to create function `mousewheel` in jQuery, when I want to check the delta the result is always "undefined". Please help me.
Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#container').bind('mousewheel', function(event,delta){
     alert(delta)

});
})
```

Comment: You need the plugin- https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/blob/master/jquery.mousewheel.js

Comment: Natively jQuery only has one parameter, the event!

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using to test in? There is more than one way to bind a mouse wheel event and depending on the browser will determine where to find the delta. In Firefox it's `event.detail` and it's values can be `1, 2, -1, -2, etc` however in non-Firefox browsers you're looking at `wheelDelta` which appears to be what you coded for.

A good resource on mousewheel events is [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/onmousewheel.shtml) which is what I used when I wrote my jQuery mousewheel plugin.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write your own plugin.  Use this [script](https://raw.github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/master/jquery.mousewheel.js) and you should be good to go!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/master/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/WmwfY/

Side Note:
Just a suggestion, you may want to use [`console.log()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it) rather than `alert()` in the future.