# select the third column on a click event

Tags: jquery

I have a Datatable, that renders two imagebuttons in the first two coloumns

```
<tr>
  <td>Button 1
  <td>Button 2
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Value<td/>
```

I'm trying to capture the value for the corresponding click using this:

```
         $('[id$=releaseMessage]').click(function () {
                alert($('td:eq(2)', this).html());
            });

            $('[id$=deleteMessage]').click(function () {
                alert($('td:eq(2)', this).html());
            });
```

the Value  is different for each row, so  I can use something like this:

```
     tr:eq(0) td:first-child
```

as this will always return the first td value.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I need to capture the value in the third col for the selected image button.

Comment: I only see two columns... could you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of what you currently have?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bTdk8/

Comment: basically, when the users select either of the image buttons, the values 37 38 or 97 are returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- `IDs` ***MUST*** be unique! Use classes instead.
- Since both click events do the same thing, combine the two classes in the selector (use a comma).   `$('.releaseMessage, .deleteMessage').click()`.
- Side Note: I recommend using [`console.log()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it) rather than `alert()`.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.releaseMessage, .deleteMessage').click(function(){
        alert($(this).closest('tr').children().eq(2).html());
    });
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/tcyuF/3/

---

EXPLANATION:

`$(this)` refers to the clicked element (in this case the anchor, `a`) 
 
[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) finds the closest `tr` 
[`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) gets the children of `tr` 
[`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) identifies the position (using index) of element

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions!