# Consuming the data returned from a jQuery AJAX call to a WCF Service

Tags: wcf, jquery, c#-4.0

Created a very simple WCF function that returns a string.

```
public interface IDataService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke( Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json )]
    string DoWork( );
}

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements( RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed )]
public class DataService : IDataService
{
    public string DoWork( )
    {
        return "DONE";
    }
}
```

I call it using jQuery.ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: service + "/DoWork",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert(textStatus);       --> success
        alert(data);             --> object
        alert(data.d);           --> undefined
    },

    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

The function returns successfully.

`textStatus` displays **success**.

`data` displays **object**.

`data.d` is **undefined**.

How do I get the string returned from DoWork?

Comment: `console.log(data)` or `console.dir(data)` will give you the structure of the object so that you can figure out how to extract data from it.

Comment: @Kevin B, thanks for the tip, very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [console.log(data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it) as suggested, the result shown below was displayed:

```
Object {DoWorkResult: "DONE"}
```

The return string can then be accessed by `data.DoWorkResult`.

```
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   console.log(data);
   alert(data.DoWorkResult);
},
```

For data structures such as a list of employees, the JSON data can be accessed like an array (assuming you've configured the service to return JSON):

```
for(var i=0; i<data.GetEmployees.length; i++) {   
   console.log(data.GetEmployees[i].Name + " - " + data.GetEmployees[i].Position); 
}
```