# Call of a js-function from HTML does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to use some javascript-code within an HTML-Page, but in doesn't work (Everything inside of a Ruby on Rails project).
So i have the following HTML-Code

```
   <a href="#" compilation_id = 51 onclick="start_render(this)">Render</a>
```

What I need is to get the parameter "compilation_id" inside the js-function

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

  function start_render(event){  
         var comp_id = $(event.target).attr('compilation_id');
         alert(comp_id);
  .....
```

I use alert(comp_id) just for debugging in order to see, if I get the data appropriately. But what I get is "undefined". When I set the value of the variable inside of the js-function, everything is Ok. So,

```
  var comp_id = 51;
  alert(comp_id);
```

works well, I get "51".

What is my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: function start_render(event){  
         var comp_id = $(event).attr('compilation_id');
         alert(comp_id);

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cPwNP/ use jquery

Comment: add `class to anchor` link `eg: render` then put `$('.render').click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('compilation_id'));
})`

Comment: Consider using [`console.log`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it) instead of `alert()` for debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `this` object, which doesn't have target property.

If you want to get `event` target, change your code as

```
 function start_render(object){
     event = event || window.event 
     var comp_id = $(event.target).attr('compilation_id');
   ...
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
onclick="start_render(event)"
```

JS:

```
function start_render(e){  
     var comp_id = $(e.target).attr('compilation_id');
     alert(comp_id);
```

---

**Or:**

```
onclick="start_render(this)"
```

JS:

```
function start_render(element){  
     var comp_id = $(element).attr('compilation_id');
     alert(comp_id);
```

---

**Or:**

```
onclick="start_render()"
```

JS:

```
function start_render(){  
     var comp_id = $(event.target).attr('compilation_id');
     alert(comp_id);
```

---

**Or:**

```
onclick="start_render.call(this)"
```

JS:

```
function start_render(){  
     var comp_id = $(this).attr('compilation_id');
     alert(comp_id);
```

---

**Best way:**

```
<a href="#" compilation_id="51" id="compilation51">Render</a>
```

JS:

```
$('#compilation51').bind('click', function(){
     var comp_id = $(this).attr('compilation_id');
     alert(comp_id);
});
```