# jQuery remove div by ID on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to remove an entire div on page load. Currently I'm trying to use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#removeme").remove();
});
```

with the HTML

```
<div id="removeme">If JS enabled remove this!</div>
```

I've been searching for hours, using many variations including getElementById. No luck.

Javascript/jQuery aren't languages I use often.

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Fixed, page I was adding it to was having some issues (another dev built it). I put the code into an existing JS file instead and it works. Thank you all.

Comment: You're looking for the `<noscript>` tag.

Comment: It works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/epsZe/

Comment: Are you including jQuery?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/SCxxe/

Comment: This works for me as well.  Are you getting errors before `$("#removeme").remove();` is hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are showing in your question works, as proven by @barmar :

```
"http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/epsZe/"
```

If it doesn't work for you, it is most likely because you have an error in your Javascript **before** you reach the code displayed here. Also, ensure that you have included Jquery before-hand.

To find where previous errors could have happened, you can look inside your Javascript console. Here is a question where it is described where to find your console on most browsers :

[What is console.log and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it)

If you don't want to use the console, you can put alerts in your Javascript code until you find where they stop displaying.

Comment: Thanks i'll give that a try. Yeah I just tested it myself on a blank page and it worked perfect. However on the site I'm trying to actually have it work on its not. I'll try the console. 

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I just checked the console and I got the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function.

HTML, CSS, PHP are all easy but javascript drives me nuts :)

Comment: Let's just say Javascript is...special :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#remove').html('');
```

or

```
$('#remove').empty();
```

That will remove that text if JS is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

try this
`$("#removeme").replaceWith("");`