# What is the equivalent of str (R language) in javascript, to get the structure of an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, inspect

In R , we have the handy function `str` to inspect object that tells you the structure of an object.

Here an example used to get the structure of a parsed `json` object ( I am using `json` just to give a useful example)

```
txt = '{"name":"agstudy","job":"developer"}'
library(rjson)
obj = fromJSON(txt)
```

Now using `str`:

```
str(obj)
List of 2
$ name: chr "agstudy"
$ job : chr "developer"
```

Now using `jquery` for example I can do this for example:

```
txt = '{"name":"agstudy","job":"developer"}';
var obj = $.parseJSON(txt);
var x = '';
$.each(obj, function(key, val) {
    x = x + ' key ' + key + ' val ' + val +'\n'
  });
```

But I am looking for more handy function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have two comfortable options.

- `console.log`

  - Chrome and Firefox allow [string substituting and formatting](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console?hl=de#string_substitution_and_formatting) with "%O" contained in the first parameter for `console.log`.
- `console.dir`

Using your example object,

```
var obj = {name:"agstudy",job:"developer"};
console.log ("Formatted object %O",obj)
console.dir (obj);
```

this looks like this

- Chrome

  - `console.log`
  - [image]
  - `console.dir`
  - [image]
- Firefox *(using firebug)*

  - `console.log`
  - [image]
  - `console.dir`
  - [image]
- ... IE flaws

  - [image]

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/avemis/1/edit) as well.

If you are looking for a way to print your objects directly in a Fiddle site, taking a look at [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/avemis/1/edit), which provides a built-in console, is worth it.

[image]

Comment: +1 I like this answer. I kon about `firebug/firequery` option. I am looking for a fiddle option. When I run your fiddle I don't get any output.

Comment: @agstudy Thanks =), What do you mean by you don't get any output? Which browser are you using, and do you have the console open?

Comment: @agstudy or do you want to print the values directly in the output region of jsfiddle.net?. If so you could take a look at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/avemis/1/edit) which provides a built in console.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are, it is called `console.log` or `console.dir` :)

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(txt);
console.log(obj);
```

Then check your console.

[What is console.log and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Answer (score 1):

as i understand str function in R have aim to informate you about things in your code via R console. So, why don't you want to use javascript console for same aim?

There is a huge ammount of console commands that can show you as more info as you want:

```
console.log
console.assert
console.clear
console.count
console.debug
console.dir
console.dirxml
console.error
console.exception
console.group
console.groupCollapsed
console.groupEnd
console.info
console.profile
console.profileEnd
console.table
console.time
console.timeEnd
console.timeStamp
console.trace
console.warn
```

Docs for Google Chrome DevTools also may help you: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api

Comment: This article may be usefull ofr you too http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/console

Comment: +1 for the effort. But the answer looks a little bit "so filling".. no need to give all console options...