# Fake input text JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 HTML input fields:

```
<input type="password" maxlength="4" id="fakepassword" />
<input type="hidden" maxlength="8" id="password" />
```

How do I insert a value into the password field, when typed and when the focus is on fakepassword?
I am trying to get the value from fakepassword with the OnkeyUp event, but I am stuck at maxlength.
Is there a way to get the value from keyboard press?

My real problem is, that I have a login form and I want my password field showing only 4 characters, no matter how many character I put into it.

Please help.

Comment: Please provide your code. Both HTML and javascript. You could make a http://jsfiddle.net if you want a quicker better explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the event in jquery:

```
$('#fakepassword').on('keyup', function(e){
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)); //this logs the letter to the console.
});
```

Comment: what is console.log? and how to get string with this console.log?

Comment: Console.log will send a message to the browsers log, which is very handy when you are working with javascript. I really recommend you using it, here's how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this only for the UI? So the user won't see the *actual* length of their password, as a security precaution? You could place an image over top of the password field, and pass the click through it to the actual password field.

```
<div id="pass_div">
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" />
    <img id="pass_img" src="" />
</div>
```

The `#pass_img` will cover the actual password input, kind of "hiding" it. The image I found is only for demonstration purposes. Please find or make a better one.

http://jsfiddle.net/4ssWe/

```
<div id="pass_div">
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" />
    <img id="pass_img" src="http://i.imgur.com/1JthtLK.gif" />
</div>

#pass_div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
#pass_img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: no sir, i want this to work with function because this is a task