# on hover not working

Tags: jquery, hover, maze

i creat a maze and don't know why on hover not working 
will be happy for any help

```
$('.wall')
.bind('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).css({
        'background-color': 'green'
    });
})
```

here is the fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/6/

Comment: You have to include the jQuery library to use its functions.

Comment: You didn't include jQuery, it works once it's added  - http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/7/. In future try checking your browser's console for errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/vYt9Q/1/

Answer (score 2):

use this in jsfiddle:

in html add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

and in script do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("mouseenter",".wall",function(){
     $(this).css({
            'background-color': 'green'
        });
    });
    $(document).on('mouseleave',".wall", function () {
        $(this).css({
           'background-color': ''
        });
    });
});
```