# Display an element's code while clicking on its part

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote code that shows the whole document's HTML code in a pop-up message:

```
<label>Hai world...</label>
<p>Test</p>

$(document).click(function(event) {
    var text = $(event.target).parent().html();
    alert(text);
});
```

How can I narrow down my code to show me only the specific HTML code of the part which is clicked on, and not the whole document's HTML code?

Comment: Side note: start using [`console.log()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it) instead of alert.

Comment: @A.Wolff: You should make that an answer!

Comment: Thank's A. Wolff but whene i clicked on it message box shows code of element,whole of document and something else

Comment: @AP4MH: Yep, that’s probably going to be bubbling. Try what VickyGonsalves wrote, but with `e.target`, not `this`.

Comment: You're misusing `label`.  Labels are used with form inputs, and help aid accessibility.  This will be confusing to anyone accessing the site with a screen reader.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    var text = event.target.outerHTML;
    alert(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(event.target.outerHTML);
}, false);
```

Try this without jQuery

Comment: Wouldn’t be `this` – `e.target` rather, with the event argument.