# Difference between console.log and return in javascript?

Tags: javascript, return, console.log

What are the instances when you would use `console.log` and `return` in javascript?

I've just started learning javascript and I want to know what are some instances when I'd use them?

Comment: `console.log` is only used for debugging/informative purposes. `return` is an integral part of the Javascript language

Comment: `console.log` is the equivalent of `print` in other languages. `return` is used for returning values from a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2011/05/26/console-log-say-goodbye-to-javascript-alerts-for-debugging.aspx

> console.log will display the parameter passed to the log method in the
>   console window. Use this method to display a string or variable in the
>   console window.
>
> You can use the console class in your code as well, much like we can
>   use JavaScript alerts.
>
> ```
> <script type = "text/javascript"> 
>     function tryConsole() { 
>         console.log("hello world"); 
>     } 
> </script>
> ```

When using the `return` statement, the function will stop executing, and return the specified value.

Answer (score 5):

Actually there's nothing in common between them.

`return` - returns execution to the caller with optional result

`console.log()` - logs out information in console.

Comment: console.log is a function in javascript and return is a keyword.
console.log is used to debug/print information to the console. Return on the other hand is a call to pass the value where the call was made
console.log is not going to stop the execution while return stops the execution and return the specific value

Answer (score 1):

`Console.log` emits a message to your browsers Console, and is usually used to emit debugging messages (research your browser's developer tools)

`return` is a keyword that terminates a function and possibly returns a value to the caller of that function.

Answer (score 0):

console.log prints the string in firebug console. Just found the below link, you can refer
[What is console.log and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it)

and

return just return from the function without processing further code or you can say, A function immediately stops at the point where return is called.

Answer (score 0):

They're for completely different purposes, console.log will return the value to the browser's console if it's supported, return will return a value from the javascript function

Answer (score 0):

console.log will not influence the flow of your code. Return values will cause reactions in your script, it really matters if you return false or true or whatever. For debugging I strongly suggest using console.log.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a clousure the `return` will return some value, and `console.log` will log some value in  browser console. Console.log is like a debug tool for not good browsers like IE.