# Why wont I receive both the return statement as well as the console.log statement?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Why won't I get both the return statement as well as console.log statement results?

The console.log outputs "Emily" but it won't output the text "says, that excessive coffee is awesome!"

```
function coffeeDrink(){
    return this.name;
    console.log("says, that excessive coffee is awesome!")
}

var literalMallory = {
    name         : "Mallory",
    favDrink     : coffeeDrink
}

var literalEmily = {
    name        : "Emily",
    favDrink    : coffeeDrink
}

coffeeDrink.call(literalEmily) //outputs "Emily"
```

I am expecting it to say:
"Emily says, that excessive coffee is awesome!"

Comment: `return` exits the function immediately; any statement after it won't be executed.

Comment: You seem to be confused about what return does

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474975/what-does-return-do-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need

```
function coffeeDrink(){
    console.log(this.name + " says, that excessive coffee is awesome!");
    return this.name;
}
```

return statement exits the execution, putting it as last statement will make console.log work and also it will return the name to calleee

Comment: hey thank you!  I am a beginner, and yes, I only knew that return will return something but I had no idea that it will exit the function immediately, even though I might have learned it a few months back. Thank you so much