# How can I filter an array of strings to an array of strings that contain a specific character?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I am trying to filter an array (like `["hello", "hi", "bye"]`) for a specific character (like "h") so that it returns a new array containing only Strings that have that character (`["hello", "hi", "bye"]` -> `["hello", "hi"]`).

Here is my current code. `giveSOFT` returns `[]` for some reason.

```js
function giveSOFT(input, char) {
    var length = input.length
    var sublist = []
    var word = ""
    var w = "piss"

    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        word = input[i]
        for (let b = 0; b < word.length; b++) {
            var input = word[b]
            var n = input.includes(w)
            if (n === true) {
                console.log(input)
            }
            return sublist
        }
    }
}

var input = ["piss", "wii", "ww", "iiwi", "iii", "piss"]
var char = "i"

console.log(giveSOFT(input, char));
```

I don't understand why or how to fix this so any advice would be appreciated.

Here is my exact instructions on what I am trying to do:

> Create a function that takes two arguments: a list of words and a letter. The function should create and return a sublist of the list in the argument. The sublist should contain only those words from the original list which contain the letter passed as the second argument.
> Use .indexOf() to find if the letter passed as an argument is in the word, if it is - push it to a new list, if not - skip

Comment: `[]` means an empty array. In your case, that's `sublist`, which you initialized as `[]`, but then never modified and simply returned back at the end of the function.

Comment: `input.filter(word => word.indexOf(char) != -1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between console.log and return in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020608/difference-between-console-log-and-return-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't pushed anything to `sublist` and your second for loop isn't needed. Also your return is in your for loop not the end of the function.

```js
function giveSOFT(input, char) {
  var sublist = []
  var word

  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    word = input[i]
    if (word.indexOf(char) > -1) sublist.push(word)
  }
  return sublist
}

var input = ["piss", "wii", "ww", "iiwi", "iii", "piss"]
var char = "w"

console.log(giveSOFT(input, char));
```

Comment: You can remove needless variables.

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel like I was just being stupid, I've been working for a few hours and my brain died I guess :p

Answer (score 0):

You didn't push any word to sublist. You can use indexOf function to check that each word contains a specific char or not.
It returns the index if the character is found and -1 if not.

```js
function giveSOFT(input, char)
{
  let sublist = []

  for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    if (input[i].indexOf(char) != -1) sublist.push(input[i]);
  return sublist
}

let input = ["piss","wii","ww","iiwi","iii","piss"]
let char = "i"

console.log(giveSOFT(input,char));
```

Comment: A code only answer that doesn't explain what the problem was or how the presented code solves it is not a good answer.

Comment: Just add a description, @Scott Marcus.