# Return Statement is not doing what I would have expected

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

Here is the code.

```js
print(5);

function print(n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return;
  }
  print(n - 1); //call function recursively  
  console.log(n);
}
```

I would expect after the return statement that console.log(n) would output zero (0)because that was the value of n when I called the return statement. Instead it returns 1 - 5 ???
Return was only called once, so can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Last recursive call is when `n = 1`. As a result, last recursive call is: `print(n - 1)` --> `print(1 - 1)` --> `print(0)`. Zero is not printed because when `n = 0`, you return from the fuction - `console.log` is not reached in that function call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between console.log and return in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020608/difference-between-console-log-and-return-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your code there is an implicit return, think of the function more like this:

```
function print(n){
    if(n==0){
      return ;
    }  
    print(n-1); //call function recursively  
    console.log(n);
    return undefined;
  }
```

So when `print(n-1)` is called with `4` it'll recurse down until you get to you're value of `0`. After that however, the calling function will log the `n` value.

Essentially your return only returns to the caller, it doesn't completely unwind the callstack and prevent that `console.log` being called. It'll look something like this:

```
print(n-1); // called with 4
  print(n-1); // called with 3
    print(n-1); // called with 2
      print(n-1); // called with 1
        print(n-1); // called with 0
        return;
      console.log(n) // 1 
    console.log(n) // 2
  console.log(n) // 3
console.log(n) // 4
console.log(n) // 5
```

Comment: Thank you Ian and cherrywoods for your help. It took me a while to dig into your answers and in fact I am still reading on this confusing subject. The hidden automatic stack returns are a difficult concept to grasp but I am making progress.  Take care :)

Answer (score 0):

The print function is still called five times. The value of `n` does not propagate to the earlier calls.

The return statement does not end the whole chain of recursive calls. Execution proceeds after the return statement in the line where the exiting function was called.

If you want some code to be executed only once in a recursive function, put it before the return in the if branch:

```js
function print(n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    console.log(n);
    return;
  }
  print(n - 1); //call function recursively  
}
```