# Call code-behind function from javascript in visual webpart

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-parts, code-behind

Is it even possible? To call a code-behind c# function from javascript in a visual web part?

It is a complex function so converting all my codes to client side is not an option. I want the logic that is there in this function to happen without a page refresh. This is the background of my issue.

Thanks guys..

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery ajax to call server side method and get the response to be used in javascript. This [article](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) has simple and good example to show what you need to do.

*Code behind*

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
  [WebMethod]
  public static string GetDate()
  {
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
  }
}
```

*Javascript*

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But the URL and the example you refered talks about page methods which cannot be used in user controls like viusal web part. correct?

Comment: Web parts are added to some aspx page isn't it?

Comment: Yes ofcourse. But I tried doing it but it did not work. The example you provided, I did try. Now i'm not sure if I did some mistake or this approach will not work. Let me try again. Thank you!

Comment: You need to add jQuery for it

Comment: Yes I did all those. I made sure I did not do any obvious mistakes.

Comment: When I put an alter in the function, alert(msg), the alter is throwing the whole HTML. Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: What you return from server side method? Use console.log(msg) to get the message structure, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it

Comment: This is what I'm returning.. I will try out the console.log now. Thank you!! `[WebMethod] [ScriptMethod] public static String Server_HelloWorld() { return "Hello, How are you?"; }`

Comment: Try console.log(msg.d) and see what you get

Comment: The console is showing the entire ASPX page in the form of HTML. I saw the console in Firebug. Any other suggestions please..

Comment: One difference in my code is, the class is a webpart and not a page, `public partial class SearchBox : WebPart`

Comment: Are you sure you get aspx page from msg.d?

Comment: Yes. SInce im doing all these in a web part and added the webpart to home.aspx im seeing the whole home.aspx in the console. my bad. `success: function (result){                 
                alert("ajax --> " + result);
            }`

Comment: I think you need to make a test by using aspx and not web parts to check if it works

Comment: With aspx it will work. I already tried. So like I understood previously, this approach is not feasbile with user controles?? Guess I will not be certain about this anytime soon. Thank you for you time though.

Answer (score 0):

Why don`t you use a Webservice (Ajax-Enabled WCF Service) which can be called via AJAX?

I think this would be the clean way. Put your logic in an extra class and use this class in the webservice and your webpart. Then you cann call the Method from Code and from Javascript.

Comment: Yes that is there. But I was wondering if we can do it without the help of a webservice. Using a webservice is not an option for me, unfortunatly, until I can prove that the asked approach dose not work.