# jQuery function is not being called onclick

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function that is triggered when a button (generated via php) is clicked, the same function is working for me on a link that is created with php as well, but for some reason this one isn't even displaying a error, I checked in firebug and it seems the functions ins't being called.

I have the script on the bottom of my page:

```
<script src="js/estadoLabs.js"></script>  on the bottom of my index page, so it should be working.
```

The function itself is this one:

```
$(".btnEliminar").click(function() {
  var idAttr = $(this).attr('id');
  var id = parseInt(idAttr.substring(12));

  var request = $.ajax({
    url: "includes/functionsLabs.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {

    'call': 'displayInfoLabs',
    'pId':id},

    dataType: 'html',

  success: function(response){
    $('#info').html(response);
    }
  });
});
```

I am quite sure the php function isn't to blame because running the $query on SQL makes the change to the table I want. Just in case this is a snippet of the html generated code that has the buttons (they are successfully being displayed).

```
<input type = "button" value = "Eliminar"  class= "btnEliminar" id = "btnEliminar-'.$row['idlab'].'" />
```

I went over it quite a few times but I didn't find any glaring erros, any help would be very appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

EDIT:  PHP

Basically thanks to PollyGreek and Rafael the jQuery works, as now when clicking the button it shows me:

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\wamp\www\Proyecto\includes\functionsLabs.php on line 179. Line 179 in question is...

```
function labStatusEliminar(){

if(isset($_POST['pId'])){

    $idEliminar = $_POST['pId'];

    $msjE = eliminar($idEliminar);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($msjE)){  //<--LINE 179
        echo 
             '<p>El laboratorio: '.$row['idlab'].' ha sido eliminado de la lista</p>';
     }
    }
   }

function eliminar($idEliminar){

$query = "UPDATE labs SET estado=3 WHERE labs.idlab = $idEliminar";
    $result = do_query($query);

}
```

What this function does is taking the id of the button and finding the lab with the same id, then changing that lab's estado to 3.

When doing a select (I know the code is prone to injection >.<) I have been using something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT bk.idlab , bk.codigolab , bk.capacidad, bk.carrera, bk.ubicacion, bk.estado FROM labs as bk WHERE bk.idlab = $pId ";
```

So perhaps I need to set an "alias" to my alter statement as well?

Comment: What exactly is your question? You mean, when you replaced **<button>** tag with **<a>**, it's not working on click..

Comment: No network activity in firebug? What about showing a simple alert?

Comment: `same function is [not???] working for me on a link that is created with php as well` what does the rendered HTML for that look like? Does it have the same `btnEliminar` class?

Comment: @VishalKhode my question is: Why isn't it working if there appears to be nothing wrong with the code?

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper: Have you changed the selector and tried like **$("input.btnEliminar")**.Sometimes, simple class selector doesn't work, we need to be more precise.

Comment: @Wilmer, it seems like it isn't registering the click on button.

Comment: @MattBurland the (almost) same function IS working with another element (a link insead of button)

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper: So what, which one isn't working? The button isn't working? Also, that's not the rendered html, that's your PHP. The javascript on your page doesn't see that, it seen the HTML outputted by your PHP application - so post that.

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper mssql_fetch_assoc is this correct or mysql ? did yoy mistype mysql ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek that was a typo (which is weird cuz I copied pasted) re-checked my code and update the answer.

Comment: according to php.net http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: result:
The result resource that is being evaluated. This result comes from a call to mysql_query(). so your function eliminar , doesnt return the expected value !

Comment: @ProllyGeek, thats weird I have been using the same syntax for generating divs and the information inside the <ul> and it has been working, I only changed the process within. Added: $result = do_query($query);

Comment: im not very experienced with mysql but it appears that you have never used mysql_query in your code.

Comment: @ProllyGeek Yeah... I am trying to fix that. Thanks to your help I managed to change the estado! Now it still show me the same error but if I reload the page the div changes color (thats what changing estado does)

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper glad to help you , please choose my answer as correct answer if it helps you.

Comment: I just decided to remove the damn while altogether and use the $idEliminar instead of row. Worked like a charm, I still wonder why it wasn't working before but I guess that is to ponder on another time.

Comment: glad you solved the problem , but it makes sense , since the query wasnt even initiated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click',".btnEliminar",function() {
  var idAttr = $(this).attr('id');
  var id = parseInt(idAttr.substring(12));

  var request = $.ajax({
    url: "includes/functionsLabs.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {

    'call': 'displayInfoLabs',
    'pId':id},

    dataType: 'html',

  success: function(response){
    $('#info').html(response);
    }
  });
});
```

would you try this ?

Comment: Well it kinda worked, now firebug IS registering a call to php even though it isn't doing anything else, like changing the estado row in my table to 2.

Comment: well this must be your php code , this should be another question with a different title , and a different tag .

Comment: Indeed, nevertheless I thank you for taking the time to assist me ;D

Comment: i will be glad to help with the php code as well please make the problem more clear .

Answer (score 1):

You need to watch the future elements events, you can do that with jquery `on` method and **delegated events**.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

**Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page** at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, **use delegated events to attach an event handler**, as described next.

Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. **By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached**, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. **This element could be the container element** of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.

So instead of `$(".btnEliminar").click(function() {`

use `$("body").on("click",".btnEliminar", function() { ...`

Notice that you should replace `"body"` for a **container** that holds less elements.

You can use [`console.log`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it) to debug in javascript and check if your errors are in your PHP or not.

Comment: This worked wonderfully, because now when I click the button I get an error on my php code (line 179) and I rather take a error on a specific line before nothing happening any time of the day.

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given or some nonsense like that.