# how to show messges using javascript on browser

Tags: javascript

i want to show messages using java script for testing my code that it is working or not

```
if(true){
////show message
```

}
how i can do this using java script and how many ways are there to show messages using java script. Because i want to do logging using java script if my code is working or not

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate on what you mean by "show messages"?

Comment: "consoling" - did you mean "logging to console"?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539253/what-is-console-log

Comment: @ValeryPetrov logging

Comment: Duplicate of [What is console.log and how do I use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4743730/218196)

Comment: This is very basic stuff @Engineer. Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try alert in javascript...

```
if(true)
{
    alert("Message");
}
```

In the case of console..

```
console.log("Hello World!");
```

Comment: how i can do consoling

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to alert?

```
if(true)
{
   alert("hello world!");
}
```

or if in console

```
if(true)
{
   console.log("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: what if i want to do consoling