# My jquery Ajax code note executed perfactly this code updated the requisition but shown else part alert

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
success: function(processResultStatus) {
                    //alert(processResultStatus);
                      //$("#moduleContentViewArea").html(processResultStatus.trim());
                    if (processResultStatus == "1") {
                        alert('Requisition Updated Sucessfully!!!');
                    } else
                    {
                        alert('Requisition could not be updated!!!');
                    }
```

This code updated the requisition but its shows in alert "Requisition could not be updated" please help me to solve this problem i am new in php

Comment: what do you get when you do `console.log(processResultStatus);`?

Comment: this project is php based when i updated the requisition part then it is updated but alert box shown message requisition could not be updated

Comment: I understand the problem. Could you answer my question above? Do you know what is `console.log()`?

Comment: Have you try to debug 1st?

Comment: nope i havnt any idea about console.log()

Comment: Ok, add that code to your page, press F12 and refresh. That will open developer tools in your browser and you will see the content of processResultStatus there. You might want to read this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it

Comment: what you get when you do alert(processResultStatus * 1);

Comment: when i alert(processResultStatus * 1); its shown me the requisition updated successfully thanx Kshitiz

Comment: Kshitiz would you please tell me why "*" is used in place of "=="

Comment: @rock001, that has nothing to do with the problem. `*` is to multiply. That cannot be the solution to your question.

Comment: @Sergio, then how can i solve this problem i am not getting any idea